# How can I determine if the queue I am using is local or remote by the name alone

Tags: message-queue, msmq, messaging

I am using System.Messaging and I have a queue on my local machine.

The queue name is `.\private$\dummyQueue`

At first glance I can see that there is a period at the beginning of the name and have determined that it is a local queue. 
Is that a safe assumption to make? 
Is there a solid rule for determining if a queue is local or remote based on the name alone?

Answer (score 1):

If only it were that simple. MSMQ uses a bunch of different ways to reference a queue, from GUIDs to format names (like your example). In your case a period is always shorthand for "local". [This blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/02/26/difference-between-path-name-and-format-name-when-accessing-msmq-queues.aspx) may help.